# Get-Printer and set the output as a variable that I can use to set the default printer

Tags: powershell

I am currently getting a list of all the printers the computer is connected to. I want the printers to become a part of a list a user can then choose which printer to set as the default. It will then execute the next part of my script that I have already made that creates a document which then prints.

```
Get-Printer | Select PortName | Select-String -Pattern "SM"
```

This is what I would like the code to return

```
1. SM04
2. SM05
3. SM06
4. SM10

Please select a printer from the list: 3

Default printer has been set to: SM06.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in trying to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to js2010 and LotPings I was able to figure it out. I was even able to get a list of all the printers the computer was connected to!

Here is the code in case anyone else is trying to do something like this.

```
#Asks the user if they would like to switch the default printer
$defaultPrinter1 = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | select ShareName
$defaultPrinter1 = ("$defaultPrinter1").substring(12,4)
Write-Host "Barcodes will be printed at your default Printer. Your default printer is currently: $defaultPrinter1"
$printerConf = Read-Host "Would you like to change the default printer? Y/N"


#Switches dafault printer to the one specified by the user. 
if ($printerConf -eq "Y") 
{
    Write-Host "Here is list of connected printers`n" 
    $printerList = Get-Printer | Select PortName | Select-String -Pattern "SM" 
    $printerList-replace ".*=" -replace "}.*"
    $wshNet = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network
    $selectPrinter = Read-Host "`nWhat is the printers name?"
    $wshNet.SetDefaultPrinter($selectPrinter)

    $defaultPrinter2 = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | select ShareName 
    $defaultPrinter2 = ("$defaultPrinter2").substring(12,4)  
    Write-Host "Default Printer has been changed. It is now: $defaultPrinter2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a powershell command that can set the default printer.  Here's how I do it in wmi.  Surprisingly, get-printer doesn't return an object with a SetDefaultPrinter() method.

```
$printerObject = Get-WmiObject win32_printer | where name -eq $defaultprinter
$resultobj = $printerObject.SetDefaultPrinter()
"default $defaultprinter $($resultobj.returnvalue)"  # showing results
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Get-WmiObject` to get/set the default printer and
`Out-Gridview` with the `-PassThru` parameter to select the new default in a GUI

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\20\SO_56222678.ps1
# Save old default Printer
$OldDefaultPrinter = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query `
    "select * from Win32_Printer Where Default = TRUE" -Impersonation 3).Name

# Get-Printer matching pattern and select in Out-Gridview
$NewDefaultPrinter = (Get-Printer | Where-Object Portname -like 'SM*'| 
  Select-Object Name,Portname |
    Out-Gridview -Title 'Select a printer' -PassThru).Name

# Set selected as new default
$Null = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='$NewDefaultPrinter'").SetDefaultPrinter()

# Check new default is set
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query `
    "select * from Win32_Printer Where Default = TRUE" -Impersonation 3).Name
```